# Sass Error: Expected expression after '/*'

Tags: node.js, ruby, sass, compilation

Previously compiling our Sass files using ruby, we have switched to the node version. However, this one returns errors on comments as follows:

`Error: Expected expression.
  position: fixed     /* Here's what sticks it*/
                       ^`

Why does this happen? I've looked at the documentation and this is the exact way comments should be allowed by Sass. Any suggestions?

Comment: try to add a semi-colon before the comment `;`

Comment: Maybe it's trying to compile it as SCSS (as opposed to SASS)

Comment: SCSS needs semi-colons and brackets, right? None of our code has this. Since I don't really wanna change the whole CSS codebase I'm afraid this will not work.